# Without code, set stretchable image as UIButton background image

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a nib with a `UIButton` in it. I have a png designed to stretch, with a single pixel in the middle.

I'd like to set the png as the backgroundImage for the button. I'd like it to function as if I called `resizableImageWithCapInsets:resizingMode:` and passed `UIImageResizingModeStretch`.

Can someone give me a precise description of how I can do this without code?

So far I'm using this category:

```
@implementation UIImage (Stretch)

- (UIImage *)stretchedImage {
    CGFloat capWidth =  floorf(self.size.width / 2);
    CGFloat capHeight =  floorf(self.size.height / 2);
    UIImage *capImage = [self resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(capWidth, capWidth, capHeight, capHeight) resizingMode:UIImageResizingModeStretch];
    return capImage;
}

@end
```

And then I'm grabbing the background image out of the UIImage, stretching it and then setting it back:

```
[self.optionsButton setBackgroundImage:[[self.optionsButton backgroundImageForState:UIControlStateNormal] stretchedImage] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

It works, but I'd rather be able to do it without the code.

Edit: Since it's a single pixel, I don't see why it would need to stretch instead of tile. So an answer that makes this work with tiling would be just as good, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Won't give you the exact answer with your values but:

1. Select the image in an asset catalog.
2. In the inspector panel, go to the Attributes inspector.
3. Near the bottom, there's a Slicing section. Change it from None to "Horizontal and Vertical".
4. Select the slicing properties you need.

As a bonus, near the bottom of the main editor there's a button that says "Show Slicing". Click it, and you'll be able to preview the image slicing.

Once done, use this image as usual, and the asset catalog will give you back a resizable image.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I ended up working around this problem another way but the next time I encounter it, I will try your solution.